# Spring Security Oauth2 H2 for testing - Table "OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN" not found

Tags: spring-boot, h2, spring-security-oauth2

Here I'm using InMemoryTokenStore. I can get this TokenStore to work when running the app by doing the following:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now I can make HTTP requests to /oauth/token and get an access token. I can also access authorized resources. And, my tests are passing and creating tables even on the fly (e.g. oauth_access_token table).

However, I don't want to use InMemoryTokenStore for dev and later on production environments. So, I'm trying to use configure H2 in a test properties file for my tests only, other environments I intend to use MySQL.

So I've modified my config class:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String datasourceUrl;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String dbUsername;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String dbPassword;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(datasourceUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(dbUsername);
        dataSource.setPassword(dbPassword);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    // ...
}
```

And I have two application.properties files for each environment:

src/main/resources/application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:33067/budget?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=budget
spring.datasource.password=s3cret
```

src/test/resources/application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
```

My intention here is that the test environment will pick up the H2 db config, and others will use the MySQL db config. However, I'm seeing the following error in my tests now:

```
2019-12-30 21:09:41.627 ERROR 20628 --- [           main] o.s.s.o.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint  : Handling error: BadSqlGrammarException, PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select token_id, token from oauth_access_token where authentication_id = ?]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN" not found; SQL statement:
select token_id, token from oauth_access_token where authentication_id = ? [42102-197]

org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select token_id, token from oauth_access_token where authentication_id = ?]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN" not found; SQL statement:
select token_id, token from oauth_access_token where authentication_id = ? [42102-197]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:234) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1402) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
...
```

I can confirm that the tests are picking up the H2 config but throws an error as the table is missing. If I skip tests, then I can run the app and make HTTP requests successfully - if the table is missing in the MySQL db it creates it. InMemoryTokenStore config creates tables too so this error doesn't occur - but I don't want this for dev/prod. But the H2 config (src/test/resources/application.properties) during tests throws an error as the table is missing, so it's not creating any tables it would seem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure but try to add spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create to your test application.properties. Because as far as I know H2 won't just create the tables on startup. Or something else that I found which is to create a .sql file inside your resources folder that would create the table for you and h2 would detect it automatically

Comment: Actually, I might be mistaken. The @Entity tables seem to be created if they don't exist, but I possibly did CREATE those additional token tables manually. I just come across a tutorial I done a few weeks ago and it includes some include statements. Anyway, for now I've created a test database in MySQL and created those token tables manually, now my tests are running against that. It's good enough for now. https://medium.com/@erangadulshan.14/replace-inmemory-token-store-with-a-persistent-one-in-spring-boot-oauth2-c00a4c35f90f